# Errors in Rspec with rails 3.2 (DEPRECATION WARNING)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-3.2, autotest

I'm starting autotest  'rspec=true autotest'
and I have error (rake db:test:prepare is performed):

DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling set_table_name is deprecated. Please use `self.table_name = 'the_name'` instead. (called from include at /my_project_name/app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:2)

DEPRECATION WARNING: Factory.define is deprecated; use the FactoryGirl.define block syntax to declare your factory. (called from  at /my_project_name/spec/factories.rb:2)

DEPRECATION WARNING: Factory.define is deprecated; use the FactoryGirl.define block syntax to declare your factory. (called from  at /my_project_name/spec/factories.rb:9)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- capybara/rspec (LoadError)

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'pg', '0.14.0' # БД
gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.1' 
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

gem 'paperclip', '3.1.2'
gem 'ckeditor', '3.6.3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5' 
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.6' 
end


group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0' 
  gem 'annotate', '2.4.0' 
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'   
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '3.5.0' 
end
```

What's wrong? It's works in rails 3.1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I just upgraded to the latest version of the gem Ckeditor

Answer (score 1):

First one is deprecate message emitted by rails. It is introduced in 3.2 as I remember. Edit as directed.

Latter two are the message FactoryGirls is emitting and not rails. I guess you updated it also from old version. To eliminate error, just edit your project files as directed.

Comment: I updated the syntax of FactoryGirls, 2 last errors are disappeared.

Rails have been updated from 3.1.

Comment: There was last mistake, but I do not know where to fix that  ------ DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling set_table_name is deprecated. Please use self.table_name = 'the_name' instead. (called from include at /my_project_name/app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:2)

Comment: It should be declared in the model class (or ancestor of the class) which may be CKEditor::Asset or its ancestor. check the source code well.

Comment: /app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:2 - it contains -   include Ckeditor::Orm::ActiveRecord::AssetBase

Comment: Then, you can find some deprecates in the module.